# Cannot find the Referencing Outlets declared in Objective-C File

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I declared a UIView in the objective-C Class File (Test.m)

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) UIView *Scene1;
```

In the StoryBoard, when I am trying to make a reference outlet pointing to the view I set in the objective-C file, Scene 1 is not displayed in the list.

Note: 1. I have already pointed the view to the correct class file.
2. They are all UIView type

Here's the code of the header file (Test.h)

```
#import "JSMessagesViewController.h"

@interface Test : JSMessagesViewController

@end
```

Here's the code for the Class File Test.m

```
#import "Test.h"
#import "MessageData.h"


@interface DeerView () <JSMessagesViewDelegate, JSMessagesViewDataSource, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIActionSheetDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *messageArray;
@property (nonatomic,strong) UIImage *willSendImage;
@property (nonatomic,strong) UIView *Scene1;
@end

@implementation DeerView

@synthesize messageArray, NameInput, Scene1, Scene2, Scene3, Scene4, Name;

...

@end
```

I am a high school student and a young developer who is still learning more. Hope you can help with my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your declaration of outlet and mark it as outlet

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIView *Scene1;
```

And you don't need to declare it as a strong property if you won't remove it from subview.

Comment: That helps! I think I probably forgot that IBOutlet are the objects which will be able to point to from Views. Thanks a LOOOOOT!